# using foreach and switch to loop through an array and return different values in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, foreach

I have an array of objects that I want to loop through. Using a function, I want to give the "type" of object and get the "value" for them.

For example:

Array:

```
$scope.data = [
  {
    "type": "CUSTOMER_NO",
    "value": "12345"
  },
  {
    "type": "NAME_LINE_1",
    "value": "CURTIS"
  },
  {
    "type": "ADDR_STREET1",
    "value": "500 RODEO DR"
  },
  {
    "type": "ADDR_STREET2",
    "value": "SUITE 102, MD 0750"
  },
  {
    "type": "ADDR_CITY",
    "value": "SAINT JOSEPH"
  },
  {
    "type": "ADDR_ZIP",
    "value": "22331"
  }
]
```

controller(forloop):

```
$scope.formatAddress = function(addressInfo) {
        angular.forEach($scope.data, function(addressValue) {
         switch(addressValue.type) {
              case "CUSTOMER_NO":
                  address = addressValue.value;
                  break;
              case "ADDR_STREET1":
                  address = addressValue.value;
                  break;
              case "ADDR_STREET2":
                  address = addressValue.value;
                  break;
              case "NAME_LINE_1":
                  address = addressValue.value;
                  break;
              case "NAME_LINE_2":
                  address = addressValue.value;
                  break;
              case "ADDR_CITY":
                  address = addressValue.value;
                  break;
              case "ADDR_ZIP":
                  address = addressValue.value;
                  break;
              default:
                  address = addressValue.value;
         }
        });
        return address;
      };
```

I'm looping through the array using forEachand using switch to check which string was passed to the specific type that i want.

In the HTML:

```
 <div>{{vm.formatAddress("CUSTOMER_NO")}} - {{vm.formatAddress("NAME_LINE_1")}}</div>
 <div>{{vm.formatAddress("ADDR_STREET1")}} {{vm.formatAddress("ADDR_STREET2")}}</div>
 <div>{{vm.formatAddress("ADDR_CITY")}}, {{vm.formatAddress("CUSTOMER_NO")}} - {{vm.formatAddress("ADDR_ZIP")}}</div>
```

What I'm currently getting back is....just the customer number like so...

```
12345 - 12345
12345 12345
12345, 12345 - 12345
```

What i want to get back...

```
12345 - CURTIS
500 RODEO DR, SAINT JOSEPH
SUITE 102, MD 0750
SAINT JOSEPH, 22331
```

EDIT:

solved it using a for-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could just replace your $scope.formatAddress with this:

```
$scope.formatAddress = function(addressInfo) {
  return data.find(x => x.type === addressInfo).value;
};
```